# Two columns (side by side) from two different tables. I need an exact count with parameters in each table

Tags: sql

Trying to get two columns (side by side) of an exact count where the below queries are requesting the information.  Basically, I want to join both queries and have the counts from each query side by side.

```
select level2id,level2name,count(*) as 'Count'
from OrgHierarchy(nolock) 
where Level2name like 'A%' and contractname = 'MSSP' AND
      Patient_Status IN ('Active (WithClaims)','Deceased/Active (WithClaims)', 'Active (NoClaims)','Deceased/Active (NoClaims)' )
group by level2id,level2name
order by 3 desc 

select level2id,level2name,count(*) as 'Count'
from OrgHierarchy_LBETL4969 (nolock) 
where Level2name like 'A%' and contractname = 'MSSP' AND
      Patient_Status IN ('Active (WithClaims)','Deceased/Active (WithClaims)', 'Active (NoClaims)','Deceased/Active (NoClaims)' )
group by level2id, level2name
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: What's the database? The specifics are really important on this one.

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: The Impaler got it to work for me.  All is good in the hood!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which database you are using my best guess is:

```
select t1.level2id, t1.level2name, t1.count as count1, t2.count as count2
  from (
    select level2id,level2name,count(*) as 'Count' 
      from OrgHierarchy(nolock) 
      where Level2name like 'A%' and contractname = 'MSSP' 
        AND Patient_Status IN (
              'Active (WithClaims)', 
              'Deceased/Active (WithClaims)', 
              'Active (NoClaims)',
              'Deceased/Active (NoClaims)' )
      group by level2id,level2name
    ) t1
    full join (
    select level2id,level2name,count(*) as 'Count' 
      from OrgHierarchy_LBETL4969 (nolock)
      where Level2name like 'A%' 
        and contractname = 'MSSP'
        AND Patient_Status IN (
              'Active (WithClaims)',
              'Deceased/Active (WithClaims)',
              'Active (NoClaims)',
              'Deceased/Active (NoClaims)' )
      group by level2id,level2name
    ) t2 on t1.level2id = t2.level2id and t1.level2name = t2.level2name
  order by count1, count2;
```

Comment: AWESOME ---  I needed to remove the order by(s) and it worked.  However, both of the columns would need to be ordered in numerically while level2id and level2name should match the count. - Thoughts?

Comment: Ordered by what? level2id, level2name, count1, or count2?

Comment: Count1 and Count2

Comment: There ya go. Modified accordingly.